# Is there any increase to known security risks by mounting the EFI System Partition, on a Windows 10 PC?

Tags: vulnerability, windows-10, threat-mitigation, threats, partition

Security risks, as in malware, attackers, or known vulnerabilities.

Threats while the ESP is mounted, or after unmounting. E.g. Could it open access routes for future attackers. I aim to avoid creating new issues in the process of checking for signs of attacks. The overall intention is threat mitigation, applying an update, checking first for related existing issues.

I would be mounting the EFI System Partition (ESP) in Windows 10 with 'mountvol' in cmd.exe. Are there threats I should be aware of, while it's mounted or afterwards? Or is the ESP no more vunerable if it's mounted or not?

I am wanting to use 'mountvol' and 'dir' to check for "Recently created and locked bootloader files" as here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/blog/2023/04/11/guidance-for-investigating-attacks-using-cve-2022-21894-the-blacklotus-campaign/

To help check for BlackLotus UEFI bootkit issues, before applying this update: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5025885-how-to-manage-the-windows-boot-manager-revocations-for-secure-boot-changes-associated-with-cve-2023-24932-41a975df-beb2-40c1-99a3-b3ff139f832d

Things I have been considering are:-

- If it is possible for the mount to be completely cleaned-up and reverted (e.g. changes to permissions reset) leaving no trace anywhere as if it never happened. Of the several methods to remove the mount point /d, /p, or /r. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mountvol I do not know which would be best for future security, the most complete practical option, without causing new issues such as a distructive method, or creating new points for vulnerabilities.
- I am considering which threats could occur while the partition is mounted or afterwards, that would have been unlikely or not possible before.
- The internet connection can be removed before starting the PC. There are no adverse symptoms showing at present (no investigation methods linked to above, have been done yet). The access would be via the same PC. There is one OS.
- About the different CVE numbers in the above links. The second linked page references the first. Both CVE-2023-24932 and CVE-2022-21894 (aka Baton Drop) are described as "Secure Boot Security Feature Bypass Vulnerability" in the Microsoft MRSC Security Update Guide, and are mentioned on this page: https://msrc.microsoft.com/blog/2023/05/guidance-related-to-secure-boot-manager-changes-associated-with-cve-2023-24932/
- I don't need to make any changes within the EFI partition, just view file information.

Additional information, added 7-9-23:

- (re: hidden / system drives and malware) It occurs to me that if a hidden threat is present, it might allow attackers to use mountvol (or similar) anyway, if it's of use to them.
- FYI the machine was shut down in July and has been off ever since. Due to discovering the potential increase in risk of this vulnerability https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/source-code-for-blacklotus-windows-uefi-malware-leaked-on-github/ and attempting to mitigate risk by not allowing use of the PC until the best ways to check for, and protect against the issues are calculated.